# C# Using Variable on Different Form

Tags: c#

In form1 `dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick` i have a variable `SelectedID` which gets the value from `datagridview1`. I want to use that Vlaue in my `DataAccess` class `sqlCommand` which is in `Form2DataSetFunction()`. Then use `Form2DataSetFunction()` in `Form2_Load` to populate datagridview.
If i create a method `GetSelectedID(string GetID)` in DataAccess class, and pass `SelectedID` value from Form1 to it than how can i use that value in `Form2DataSetFunction()`.
Can anyone please help!!

**Code in Form 1**

```
    namespace myApplication
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
    private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick
    (object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            **string SelectedID** = 
            dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Form2 Form2Obj = new Form2();
            Form2Obj.ShowDialog();

        }
```

**Code in DataAccess Class**

```
    namespace myApplication
    {
    class DataAccess
    {
    public DataSet Form2DataSetFunction()
        {
                Connection details......
        SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from myTable 
        where ID='"SelectedID"'", myobjConnection);
            fill Dataset........
        return Dataset;
        }
```

**Code in Form 2**

```
    namespace Form2
    {
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
    public Barcodes()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess DataAccessObject = new DataAccess();
        DataSet Form2DatasetObject = 
                DataAccessObject.Form2DataSetFunction();
        dataGridViewForm2.DataSource = 
                Form2DatasetObject.Tables[0];
    } 
    }
    }
```

Comment: Add a public property to form2.  Populate the value when you create form2 before you .Show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
class DataAccess
{
   private readonly string _tableId;
   public DataAccess(stirng TableId)
   {
      _tableId = tableId;
   }
   // other stuff
}
```

use **_tableId** in **Form2DataSetFunction** function

Form2 should have argument in constructor too

```
public class Form2
{
    private readonly DataAccess _dataAccess;

    public Form2(DataAccess dataAccess)
    {
        _dataAccess = dataAccess;
    }

    // use given _dataAccess in FormLoad instead of creating one.
}
```

Form1 in your handler

```
Form2 Form2Obj = new Form2(new DataAccess(dataGridViewProcess.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString()));
Form2Obj.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I figured it out, Your answer helped so i Marked it as answer

Comment: AFAIK The VS designer requires an empty constructor, so this advice as is will break the designer with nasty error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a classic 'Master-Details" type of operations. I've posted the solution for `SqlDataSource/GridView` controls included in ASP.NET ([**link**](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/225352/Nesting-GridView-control-in-ASP-NET)).

Essentially, it can be solved by passing the cell value as a parameter:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    SqlDataSource s = (SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource2");
    s.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
  }
}
```

or a better version using `DataKeys`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
     // find DataSource used for nested GridView (could be SqlDataSource)
     AccessDataSource s = (AccessDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("dsMusic");
     // assign parameter’s default value from the DataKeys in GridView1
     s.SelectParameters[0].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(((GridView)sender).DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values["Composer"]);
   }
}
```

Hope this can help. Regards, Alex

PS. Here is a sample practical implementation of nested GridView controls as described above: [demo](http://webinfocentral.com/WebTV/ClassicMusic.aspx#navClassical)

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you two options one is to put a parameter in your constructor for Form2:

```
public Form2(String passID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

But before that you have a private variable for the SelectID in your form2 like

```
  String SelectID
```

So, you will have now:

```
     public Form2(String passID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SelectID=passID;
    }
```

Later on if you want to call Form2DataSetFunction() you can have then this code:

```
  Form2DataSetFunction(passID);
```

Another is to create a Property in your form like

```
public String passSelectID { get; set; }
```

then in when you initialize form2 you could say:

```
Form2 Form2Obj = new Form2();
Form2Obj.passSelectID = SelectedID;
        Form2Obj.ShowDialog();
```