# Pass list to another form

Tags: c#, oop, object, static

I have a class that has several `lists`. The name of this class is `Trans` .
I want use this lists in **another forms** but I'm not able to call it's `lists`.
When I make an object from the `Trans` class it's lists will reset.
How can I use this lists in all of forms of the project ?

```
class Trans
{
    public static List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> family_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> phoneno_list = new List<string>();

    public  List<string> name_Sec_list { set { name_list = value; } get { return name_list; } }
    public  List<string> family_Sec_list { set { name_list = value; } get { return name_list; } }
    public  List<string> phoneno_Sec_list { set { name_list = value; } get { return name_list; } }
}
```

And `Form1`

```
Trans data = new Trans();
data.name_Sec_list.Add(name.Text);
data.family_Sec_list.Add(name.Text);
data.phoneno_Sec_list.Add(name.Text);
```

When I'm on Form2 and wanna to use my lists I can't So I should make object from Trans class and this work will make list values `null`.

Comment: Make that class or lists static and use your lists like: `Trans.name_list` without creating `new Trans()`

Comment: @MarkBenovsky Which class should be static ?

Comment: `public static class Trans`, or you can make all your lists `static` like `name_list`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688552/how-can-i-replace-text-in-richtextbox-form-another-form

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18034730/how-can-i-fill-a-class-prperty-form-another-class

Comment: @MamadFr added answer how to use your class lists as static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Using Variable on Different Form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410650/c-sharp-using-variable-on-different-form)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a singleton pattern:

```
class Trans {

    private static Trans instance;

    private Trans() { }

    public static Trans Instance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Trans();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    ...
}
```

use it in first form:

```
Trans trans = Trans.Instance();
trans.name_Sec_list ....
```

use it in second form:

```
Trans trans = Trans.Instance();
trans.name_Sec_list ....
```

Comment: Singletons are a kind of anti-pattern and not so much different from static members. Singletons can be used from everywhere, encouraging spaghetti code.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The question is how the data/object can be passed to another form, this is only one possible solution (never said that it is the perfect solution).

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, a quick solution could be to make the properties static. However, this will likely introduce new problems such as testability, and it violates clean code principles.

The Singleton approach is already better, since the you could potentially make it configurable to return a test object for unit tests. However, getting the Singleton requires a static method, which can again be called all over the place.

So, both, static properties and Singletons will increase the likelyness of Spaghetti code. That's because you have no control over who can access the data and who cannot.

You have not exactly specified how many forms you have, how they are opened etc. so I will need to make some assumptions.

The main method could look like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var data = new Trans();
    var secondForm = new Form2 {Trans = data};
    var mainForm = new Form1 {SubForm = secondForm, Trans = data };
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

And I have modified the Trans class so that it does not have static items any more. I also fixed that class, because IMHO it had a copy/paste problem. It's likely that you introduced all the `_Sec_` stuff for testing purposes, so they can likely be removed (they return the same object, which doesn't solve any problem).

```
class Trans
{
    public List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
    public List<string> family_list = new List<string>();
    public List<string> phoneno_list = new List<string>();

    public List<string> name_Sec_list { set { name_list = value; } get { return name_list; } }
    public List<string> family_Sec_list { set { family_list = value; } get { return family_list; } }
    public List<string> phoneno_Sec_list { set { phoneno_list = value; } get { return phoneno_list; } }
}
```

What can you see here?

- both, `Form1` and `Form2` have access to the data, so it solves your problem.
- the `Main()` method has control over who gets which data. Everyone who needs that data gets the data.
- Nobody else gets access to the data. While everyone could `new` up a `Trans` himself, that would just be empty.
- Since there's nothing `static` any more, you can safely use `new` instances of `Trans` during unit tests without any side effects
- The forms do not create their dependencies themselves. The dependency is now injected into the form. This makes it possible to replace it by a mock object with defined test behavior in a unit test. (Another question is whether you should test UIs in unit tests, but that's a different topic).

Comment: i won't use list as public.

Comment: I see. I suppose if you've a larger number of forms, these could be instanced via a form factory which could ultimately control the injection of the trans class. thanks

Comment: @MamadFr: probably true. I didn't want to modify OP's code too much.

Comment: @Wheels73: yes, exactly, a Factory or Builder should help in such a case.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a static class

```
  public static class Trans
    {
        public static List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> family_list = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> phoneno_list = new List<string>();
    }
```

Usage

```
Trans.name_list.Add(string);
```

I'd put the static class in a separate project so it can be referenced elsewhere if needed. But only if needed.

Comment: Everything should be static by default in .NET anyway. It's much more convenient to have global access to everything.

Comment: Why not? I think it's "not useful" and that's exactly what's in the description of the down arrow.

Comment: Because the solution works. Add a static class to a winforms project and I can access the lists from any form. if I'm missing something then please explain so we can learn.

Comment: Static things as well as Singletons increase the likelyness of spaghetti code. With your code, the form retrieves the dependencies itself. Instead, it should get the dependencies from outside (dependency injection). It makes your code hard to test, because you cannot exchange the static class with a different object that has test behavior.

Comment: Agreed...and I'm well versed on the use of DI, IOC and mocking frameworks, but where did the question specify that he needs to be able run unit tests. Look, i'm not being funny, but I'm new to this site and it seems some people are far to quick to down vote. If my answer was irrelevant then I wouldn't mind. You're attempting to provide an answer that solves a problem he didn't ask.

Comment: I think the proposal is more a workaround ("make it work") than a solution ("not needed to change in the future"). I know, the fastest gun in the west is going to make points on SO, but I still prefer solutions where I can learn something from and not a solution which will likely require a follow-up question, which is like this: "I was advised to make everything static. Now my unit tests are broken. How do I fix it?" - and the answer to that is: revert everything and do it right.

Comment: Again I agree to an extent there.. but a lot of time there is a strong case for "Make in work". Sometimes code can be over engineered when really it just needs to solve the problem. If you posted a solution to the poster where the dependency was injected.. i'm wondering if they would then need clarification as to implementation provided given the question that was asked. Anyway... thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Know what: I'm very late in providing an answer now. I have seen all ideas from other answerers. I don't find any better solutions than I can think of, so I could now provide an answer that a) solves OP's issues and b) does not have other disadvantages. Maybe it gets accepted, maybe it doesn't. Maybe I get rep, maybe I don't. But it will be helpful for the OP and for others coming here in the future. See [an answer of Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41881377/480982): he was late, but still provides an excellent point to learn from. His post does not even answer OP's question.

Comment: BTW: Thanks for asking for feedback. Highly appreciated. Being open minded is one of the most important characteristics of a developer.

Comment: I won't use my list as public.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 static lists in your `Trans` class already, if you want to use them make other also static:

```
public class Trans
{
    public static List<string> name_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> family_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> phoneno_list = new List<string>();

    public static List<string> name_Sec_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> family_Sec_list = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> phoneno_Sec_list = new List<string>();
}
```

Then everywhere you want to use these lists you should access them like:

```
Trans.name_Sec_list.Add(name.Text);
```

Now you can use these lists in any form that you want.

Comment: I won't use my list as public.